# org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()? Build info: version: '3.0.1',

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit

```
package com.epath.smoketest.tests;


import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.TestRule;
import org.junit.rules.TestWatcher;
import org.junit.runner.Description;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import com.epath.smoketest.pageobjects.AiccAdd;
import com.epath.smoketest.pageobjects.AudioAdd;
import com.epath.smoketest.pageobjects.CustomAdd;
import com.epath.smoketest.pageobjects.DocumentAdd;
import com.epath.smoketest.pageobjects.ImageAdd;
import com.epath.smoketest.pageobjects.LearningActivityAdd;
import com.epath.smoketest.pageobjects.LinkAdd;
import com.epath.smoketest.pageobjects.Login;
import com.epath.smoketest.pageobjects.Navigation;
import com.epath.smoketest.pageobjects.RegistrationCreate;
import com.epath.smoketest.pageobjects.ScormAdd;
import com.epath.smoketest.pageobjects.VideoAdd;

public class Test1 extends TestWatcher  {


    private Login login;
    private Navigation go;
    private LearningActivityAdd addLa;
    private ImageAdd addImage;
    private DocumentAdd addDocument;
    private VideoAdd addVideo;
    private AudioAdd addAudio;
    private LinkAdd addLink;
    private CustomAdd addCustom;
    private AiccAdd addAicc;
    private ScormAdd addScorm;
    private RegistrationCreate createRegistration;
    WebDriver driver;

     public Utils utils = new Utils(driver);

    @Before
    public void setUp()
    {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\Required Software For Automation\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");

    //  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D:\\Required automation files\\geckodriver-v0.19.1-win32\\geckodriver.exe");
    //  driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        login = new Login(driver);
        go = new Navigation(driver);        
        addLa = new LearningActivityAdd(driver);
        addImage = new ImageAdd(driver);
        addDocument = new DocumentAdd(driver);
        addVideo = new VideoAdd(driver);
        addAudio = new AudioAdd(driver);
        addLink = new LinkAdd(driver);
        addCustom = new CustomAdd(driver);
        addAicc = new AiccAdd(driver);
        addScorm = new ScormAdd(driver);

        createRegistration = new RegistrationCreate(driver);

     }

    @Rule
    public TestRule listen = new TestWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void failed(Throwable t, Description description) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Test case failed");
                captureScreenShot(description.getClassName() + "," + description.getMethodName());  
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
        }
    };

    public void captureScreenShot(String fileName)  {
                System.out.println("Inside capture function");
                try {
                File scrFile =((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
                System.out.println("Screenshot captured");
                File targetFile = new File("\\\\192.168.11.32\\admin\\resources\\" + fileName + ".png");
                FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, targetFile);
                System.out.println("Completed screenshot functionality");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

     @Test
        public void Shallow() throws Exception {

            int maxLAs = 1000;
            int maxRegs = 1000;

            // Print to screen to create log.  Log can be copied and pasted to Word document or elsewhere as needed.
            System.out.println("\n" + "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Adding and Registering Learning Activities Automation");
            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

            // Load the properties
            System.out.println("\n" + "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Read in PROPERTIES file");
            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

            Properties prop = new Properties();
            InputStream input = null;

            String inputFS = "\\\\192.168.11.32\\admin\\resources\\AddRegisterLAs.properties";
            input = new FileInputStream(inputFS);
            prop.load(input);

            // Input file with test data 
            String testInputFile = prop.getProperty("test_input_file");
            System.out.println("\t" + "testInputFile =" + testInputFile);

            // Input file for importing users 
            String userImportFile = prop.getProperty("user_import_file");
            System.out.println("\t" + "user_import_file =" + userImportFile);

            // URL to test 
            String testUrl = prop.getProperty("test_url");
            System.out.println("\t" + "testUrl =" + testUrl);

            // Testing client credentials 
            String ngage_username = prop.getProperty("ngage_username");
            String ngage_password = prop.getProperty("ngage_password");
            String ngage_orgcode = prop.getProperty("ngage_orgcode");
            System.out.println("\t" + "nGage client credentials: U:" + ngage_username + " P:" + ngage_password + " O:" + ngage_orgcode);

            // ePath client credentials 
            String epath_username = prop.getProperty("epath_username");
            String epath_password = prop.getProperty("epath_password");
            String epath_orgcode = prop.getProperty("epath_orgcode");
            System.out.println("\t" + "ePath client credentials: U:" + epath_username + " P:" + epath_password + " O:" + epath_orgcode);

            // Load the path of the resources folder, containing files to be tested 
            String resourcesPath = "\\\\192.168.11.32\\admin\\resources\\";
            System.out.println("\t" + "resourcesPath =" + resourcesPath);

            String uniqueString = "";


            System.out.println("\n" + "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Read in INPUT file describing LAs and Registrations");
            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

            String inputDataFS = resourcesPath + testInputFile;
            InputStream inputData = null;
            inputData = new FileInputStream(inputDataFS);

            Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputData);

            Sheet lasSheet = workbook.getSheet("LAs");
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = lasSheet.iterator();

            //  Maximum maxLAs learning activities may be specified, at this time
            //  First row must contain labels
            String listLearningActivities[][] = new String[maxLAs+1][4];
            int numberLearningActivities = 0;
            int r = 0;
            int c = 0;
            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                Row nextRow = rowIterator.next();                                
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();

                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                    listLearningActivities[r][c] = cell.getStringCellValue();
                    // System.out.print("\n" + " r=" + r + " c=" + c + " content=" + listLearningActivities[r][c] ); 
                    c = c + 1;
                    }
                r = r + 1;
                c = 0;
            }
            workbook.close();
            inputData.close();
            numberLearningActivities = r-1;
            System.out.println("\t" + "Completed reading Excel file that describes Learning Activities.  # LAs = " + numberLearningActivities);


//          Now let's read the Registration data        
            Sheet registrationSheet = workbook.getSheet("Registrations");
            rowIterator = registrationSheet.iterator();

//          First row must contain labels.
            String listRegistrationInfo[][] = new String[maxRegs+1][9];
            int numberRegistrations = 0;
            r = 0;
            c = 0;
            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                Row nextRow = rowIterator.next();                                
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();

                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                    listRegistrationInfo[r][c] = cell.getStringCellValue();
                     // System.out.print("\n" + " r=" + r + " c=" + c + " content=" + listRegistrationInfo[r][c] ); 
                    c = c + 1;
                    }
                r = r + 1;
                c = 0;
            }
            workbook.close();
            inputData.close();
            numberRegistrations = r-1;
            System.out.println("\t" + "Completed reading Excel file that describes requested Registrations.  # Registrations = " + numberRegistrations);


            System.out.println("\n" + "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Begin working in client described in properties file. ");
            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

            login.with("testurl", ngage_username, ngage_password, ngage_orgcode, "welcome1"); 
            assertTrue("-------------------- Dashboard welcome message not present.", login.successMessagePresent());



//          Add the learning activities specified in the Excel input file
            System.out.println("\n" + "----------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Add all learning activities described in input file ");
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------");

            r = 0;
            c = 0;
            //  Start with row1, not row0, since row0 has column labels.
            for (r=1; r<=numberLearningActivities; r++) {
                    switch (listLearningActivities[r][0]) {
                    case "Image":
                        go.toAddLearningActivity();
                        assertTrue("-------------------- Add LA page not present.",  addLa.initSuccess());
                        addLa.addImage();
                        assertTrue("-------------------- Add image page not present.",  addImage.initSuccess());
                        addImage.of(resourcesPath + listLearningActivities[r][1], listLearningActivities[r][2] + uniqueString, listLearningActivities[r][3]);
                        assertTrue("-------------------- Adding of image LA was not successful.",  addImage.addSuccess());
                        break;

                    case "Document":
                        go.toAddLearningActivity();
                        assertTrue("-------------------- Add LA page not present.",  addLa.initSuccess());
                        addLa.addDocument();
                        assertTrue("-------------------- Add document page not present.",  addDocument.initSuccess());
                        addDocument.of(resourcesPath + listLearningActivities[r][1], listLearningActivities[r][2] + uniqueString, listLearningActivities[r][3]);
                        assertTrue("-------------------- Adding of document LA was not successful.",  addDocument.addSuccess());
                        break;

                    case "Video":
                        go.toAddLearningActivity();
                        assertTrue("-------------------- Add LA page not present.",  addLa.initSuccess());
                        addLa.addVideo();
                        assertTrue("-------------------- Add video page not present.",  addVideo.initSuccess());
                        addVideo.of(resourcesPath + listLearningActivities[r][1], listLearningActivities[r][2] + uniqueString, listLearningActivities[r][3]);
                        assertTrue("-------------------- Adding of video LA was not successful.",  addVideo.addSuccess());
                        break;

                    case "Audio":
                        go.toAddLearningActivity();
                        assertTrue("-------------------- Add LA page not present.",  addLa.initSuccess());
                        addLa.addAudio();
                        assertTrue("-------------------- Add audio page not present.",  addAudio.initSuccess());
                        addAudio.of(resourcesPath + listLearningActivities[r][1], listLearningActivities[r][2] + uniqueString, listLearningActivities[r][3]);
                        assertTrue("-------------------- Adding of audio LA was not successful.",  addAudio.addSuccess());
                        break;

                    case "Link":
                        go.toAddLearningActivity();
                        assertTrue("-------------------- Add LA page not present.",  addLa.initSuccess());
                        addLa.addLink();
                        assertTrue("-------------------- Add link page not present.",  addLink.initSuccess());
                        addLink.of(listLearningActivities[r][1], listLearningActivities[r][2] + uniqueString, listLearningActivities[r][3]);
                        assertTrue("-------------------- Adding of link LA was not successful.",  addLink.addSuccess());
                        break;


                    case "Custom":
                            go.toAddLearningActivity();
                        assertTrue("-------------------- Add LA page not present.",  addLa.initSuccess());
                        addLa.addCustom();
                        assertTrue("-------------------- Add custom html page not present.",  addCustom.initSuccess());
                        addCustom.of(resourcesPath + listLearningActivities[r][1], listLearningActivities[r][2] + uniqueString, listLearningActivities[r][3]);
                        assertTrue("-------------------- Adding of custom LA was not successful.",  addCustom.addSuccess());
                        break;


                    case "AICC URL":
                        go.toAddLearningActivity();
                        assertTrue("-------------------- Add LA page not present.",  addLa.initSuccess());
                        addLa.addAicc();
                        assertTrue("-------------------- Add aicc page not present.",  addAicc.initSuccess());
                        addAicc.of("Remote", listLearningActivities[r][1], listLearningActivities[r][2] + uniqueString, listLearningActivities[r][3]);
                        assertTrue("-------------------- Adding of aicc by URL LA was not successful.",  addAicc.addSuccess());
                        break;

                    case "AICC":
                        go.toAddLearningActivity();
                        assertTrue("-------------------- Add LA page not present.",  addLa.initSuccess());
                        addLa.addAicc();
                        assertTrue("-------------------- Add aicc page not present.",  addAicc.initSuccess());
                        addAicc.of("Local", resourcesPath + listLearningActivities[r][1], listLearningActivities[r][2] + uniqueString, listLearningActivities[r][3]);
                        assertTrue("-------------------- Adding of aicc by filename LA was not successful.",  addAicc.addSuccess());
                        break;

                    case "SCORM":
                        go.toAddLearningActivity();
                        assertTrue("-------------------- Add LA page not present.",  addLa.initSuccess());
                        addLa.addScorm();
                        assertTrue("-------------------- Add custom html page not present.",  addScorm.initSuccess());
                        addScorm.of(resourcesPath + listLearningActivities[r][1], listLearningActivities[r][2] + uniqueString, listLearningActivities[r][3]);
                        assertTrue("-------------------- Adding of scorm LA was not successful.",  addScorm.addSuccess());
                        break;

                    default:
                        System.out.println("\t" + " r=" + r + " is an unrecognized type of" + listLearningActivities[r][0]); 

                    }
            }


            System.out.println("\n" + "----------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Perform all Registrations described in input file ");
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------");

//          //-Column indices
            int cLaType = 0;
            int cLaTitle = 1;
            int cRegName = 2;
            int cRegType = 3;
            int cPeople = 4;
            int pType =5;
            int cDueDate = 6;
            int cTrack = 7;
            int cAccess = 8;
            int calNo =2;

            for (r=1; r<=numberRegistrations; r++) {
                go.toWorkspace();

                createRegistration.with
                (listRegistrationInfo[r][cLaType] , 
                        listRegistrationInfo[r][cLaTitle]  + uniqueString, 
                        listRegistrationInfo[r][cRegName], 
                        listRegistrationInfo[r][cRegType], 
                        listRegistrationInfo[r][cPeople],
                        listRegistrationInfo[r][pType],
                        listRegistrationInfo[r][cDueDate], 
                        listRegistrationInfo[r][cTrack], 
                        listRegistrationInfo[r][cAccess],
                        calNo);
                calNo=calNo+2;
                 assertTrue("-------------------- Creating a registration was not successful.",  createRegistration.addSuccess());
            }

            // Logout as System Administrator
           go.toSignOut();

           System.out.println("\n" + "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
           System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
           System.out.println("Adding and registering of LAs is Complete!");
           System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
           System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

        }

        @After
        public void teardown () {

            driver.quit();
        }


}
```

I am trying to capture screenshot for failed test cases but i am facing this issue.
    Error is

=======================================================

Error coming as :

```
Test case failed
Inside capture function
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700'
System info: host: 'c02win', ip: '192.168.11.42', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_152'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:130)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:658)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.getScreenshotAs(RemoteWebDriver.java:340)
    at com.epath.smoketest.tests.Test1.captureScreenShot(Test1.java:105)
    at com.epath.smoketest.tests.Test1$1.failed(Test1.java:95)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher.failedQuietly(TestWatcher.java:84)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher.access$300(TestWatcher.java:46)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:62)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:539)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:761)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:207)
```

Comment: Which chrome driver version you are using

Comment: Hi Ankur I am using chrome driver 2.33 version

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are executing your code to take a screenshot in the 'failed'-phase. At this point, the test has already failed and the driver has already been shutdown. What you need to do is put your logic to capture a screenshot in the 'evaluate'-phase.
In this phase you can check for exceptions and when an exception occured, take the screenshot. Something like:

```
        @Override
        public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
            try {
                statement.evaluate();
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                // exception will be thrown only when a test fails.
                captureScreenShot(frameworkMethod.getName());
                // rethrow to allow the failure to be reported by JUnit
                throw t;
            }
        }
```

Comment: now error coming   Inside capture function
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.epath.smoketest.tests.ScreenShotRule.captureScreenShot(ScreenShotRule.java:36)
 at com.epath.smoketest.tests.ScreenShotRule.failed(ScreenShotRule.java:27)
 at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher.failedQuietly(TestWatcher.java:84)

Comment: I have changed annotation from @ After to @ AfterClass and now this class is working fine .  Now i have created new class with failed test case code and now i am calling this class object in my above test case like       @ Rule Screenshot screenshot = new Screenshot(driver); I am getting above error  java.lang.NullPointerException  and this null pointer is coming for this line   "File scrFile =((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);"         Can you suggest me.

Comment: Try and debugging your code, I am 99% sure that your driver instance is null or empty.

Comment: Yes you are right my driver instance showing null. But i have set global driver variable in both class .   same driver variable is working fine with other methods   . I am getting driver null error only with failed method.

Comment: This issue is resolved thank you very much for your help guys

Comment: you can mark the answer @TarunDabbs